# Visualizar tempo de requisição HTTP e Processo do Java no Eclipse

Tags: java, java-ee, eclipse

Gostaria de calcular e visualizar o tempo e os recursos gasto de quando o servidor com JAVA recebe uma requisição, do momento em que recebe até o momento em resposta.

Comment: JProfile - https://www.ej-technologies.com/download/jprofiler/files

Comment: Perfino Monitor - https://www.ej-technologies.com/download/perfino/files
Você vai conseguir usar os dois por 30 dias gratis.

Comment: Qual a diferença dos dois ? Achei também o Java Mission Control ? Qual deles é mais intuitivo ?

Comment: Jprofiler é muito intuitivo, só que ele vai dar quanto do método do seu 
está ocupando de memoria, gráfico, GC, Grafico de Transações JDBC;

Vai te dar a arvóre de execução completa é otimo, exemplo das strings;

As vezes o retorno de um resultset, esquecemos de dar um new string dentro de um while() e a GC não finaliza então temos heap crescente o jprofile consegue identificar isso;

Enquanto o perfino faz o profile do server, numero de requisições, graficos da requisição quanto tempo gastou. Até hoje não vi nada que  juntasse os dois o Xrebel promete mas é muito complicado.